# HTML: Why does The <input> tag with type email is not including number of spaces to its content length

Tags: html

In HTML the `input` tag with type `email` is not including number of spaces to its length. It is showing length of `value` as 0 for any number of spaces, but if you see visually the browser will show spaces in email input box.

But the `input` tags with other type are counting the spaces along with the alphanumeric data.

What was the wrong here or am I missing any concept here?

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var input = e.target;
    console.log(input.id + ": length = " + input.value.length);
  });
}
```

```css
input { display: block;}
```

```html
<label for='email'>Email</label>
<input type='email' id='email'>

<label for='text'>Text</label>
<input type='text' id='text'>
```

Comment: Please show a working example of your code that outlines the issue.

Comment: Maybe the type email included already some kind of internal removement of spaces since they are not allowed in email addresses

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in the HTML standard. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)

The browser is applying the [value sanitization algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) as specified for the `email` type.

> The [value sanitization algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) is as follows: [Strip newlines](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) from the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value), then [strip leading and trailing ASCII whitespace](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#strip-leading-and-trailing-ascii-whitespace) from the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value).

Comment: Yes i have got this Standard specific to email, i hope it could be better if email tag performs event.preventDefault() on space/s event. So by doing this, the browser will not show space/s which is not required.